# Typescript conditionally constricted string union

Tags: typescript

I'm currently making an abstracted component for a modal. It can have one, two, or three call to actions (buttons, links, etc.)

The modal will have [`role="alertdialog"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_alertdialog_role), meaning I should identify the safest item to initially focus on for accessibility purposes. The modal conditionally renders typical "X" close button in the upper-right corner.

I'm using overloading to get as far as I have gotten, but I'd only like `'xButton'` to be in the union type option if `"withCloseButton"` is `true`. Is this possible without generics? If it requires generics, is there a way to do an inference generic?

```js
type ForwardRefRenderFn = React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<any, { [key: string]: any }>;

type CTAItem = CTAModalButton | ForwardRefRenderFn;

type OneCTA = {
  primaryCTA: CTAItem;
  secondaryCTA: undefined;
  tertiaryCTA: undefined;
  leastDestructiveElement: 'primaryCTA' | 'xButton';
};

type TwoCTAs = {
  primaryCTA: CTAItem;
  secondaryCTA: CTAItem;
  tertiaryCTA: undefined;
  leastDestructiveElement: 'primaryCTA' | 'secondaryCTA' | 'xButton';
};

type ThreeCTAs = {
  primaryCTA: CTAItem;
  secondaryCTA: CTAItem;
  tertiaryCTA: CTAItem;
  leastDestructiveElement: 'primaryCTA' | 'secondaryCTA' | 'tertiaryCTA' | 'xButton';
};

export type TransactionModalProps = ModalProps & (OneCTA | TwoCTAs | ThreeCTAs) &
  { withCloseButton?: boolean };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but something like this might help:

```js
type OneCTA<T> = {
  primaryCTA: CTAItem;
  secondaryCTA: undefined;
  tertiaryCTA: undefined;
  leastDestructiveElement: 'primaryCTA' | T;
};

type TransactionModalProps<T> = T extends { withCloseButton: true }
  ? OneCTA<'xButton'> | TwoCTAs<'xButton'> | ThreeCTAs<'xButton'>
  : OneCTA<unknown> | TwoCTAs<unknown> | ThreeCTAs<unknown>;
```